# Protection against scrapping with nginx

Tags: nginx, ddos, web-crawler, flooding, scraping

This morning we had a crawler going nuts on our server hitting our site almost 100 times per second.

We'd like to add a protection for this.

I guess I'' have to use [HttpLimitReqModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitReqModule) but I don't want to block allow google/bing/... How should I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Arno's Iptables scripts with enabled IDS plugin. It will do the job for you. [Link](http://rocky.eld.leidenuniv.nl/joomla)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [ngx_http_limit_conn_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html)